# Javascript SDK channelUrl for local development

Tags: support, javascript, oauth2

I am trying to get started with [the Javascript SDK](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib). I am developing on a web server on my local machine. I get a `channelUrl`-related error when calling `SE.init`.

My code:

```
SE.init({
    clientId: 12345,
    key: 'my key',
    channelUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/blank',
    complete: function (data) { console.log(data) }
})
```

I receive the error message:

```
Uncaught channelUrl must be under the current domain
```

The minified source seems to indicate that the `channelUrl` parameter should match `window.location.host`, which in my case is `localhost:8000`.

I have also unsuccessfully tried `localhost:8000/blank` and `localhost:8000`.

What value should I use for the `channelUrl` parameter?

Answer (score 7):

Your value for `channelUrl` is nominally correct.  If I set up my XAMPP server, via `httpd.conf` to use port 8000, then this HTML page works perfectly fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>StackApps SDK auth test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head><body>

<p>See the console.</p>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://api.stackexchange.com/js/2.0/all.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SE.init ( {
        clientId:   1543,
        key:        '{USE YOUR OWN KEY}',
        channelUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/test/blank.htm',
        complete:   function (data) { console.log ("Init: ", data); }
    } );
</script>
</body></html>
```

-- where `blank.htm` is a completely empty file and I access the page with this URL: `http://localhost:8000/test/StckApps_SDK_auth_test.htm`

The console shows:

```
Init: Object { version="11633"}
```

So, **something you are not showing us is the problem**.  (Redirects? Using `file://` protocol?  Typos? Other?)

---

However, there is an apparent bug in the SDK.  It apparently **does not account for ports when you try to do the next step (`SE.authenticate()`).**

Consider this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>StackApps SDK auth test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head><body>

<p>See the console.</p>
<p><button id="authBtn">Get authorized.</button></p>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://api.stackexchange.com/js/2.0/all.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready (jQueryMain);

    function jQueryMain () {
        $("#authBtn").click ( function () {
            SE.authenticate ( {
                success:    function (data) { console.log ("Auth success: ", data); },
                error:      function (data) { console.log ("Auth error: ", data); },
                scope:      ['read_inbox'],
                networkUsers: true
            } );
        } );
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SE.init ( {
        clientId:   1543,
        key:        '{USE YOUR OWN KEY}',
        channelUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/test/blank.htm',
        complete:   function (data) { console.log ("Init: ", data); }
    } );
</script>
</body></html>
```

When I click on the <kbd>Get authorized.</kbd> button, a popup appears with a valid access token in the URL.  But this information never gets back to the calling page!
The Firefox Error Console reports:

> Security Error: Content at `http://localhost/` may not load data from `http://localhost:8000/test/StckApps_SDK_auth_test.htm`.

Note the port mismatch in what the SDK tries to use?  **This looks like a bug.**

If I change the page, edit my [app settings](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/), and reset XAMPP to use `localhost` without any port specified (except 80 in httpd.conf), then the page works perfectly and I get a response like:

> Auth success: Object { accessToken="72L6...2W6cH(kQ))", expirationDate=Date, networkUsers=[23]}

in the Firebug console.

---

So, even if you get the first part working, you do not want to use a non-default port with the SDK, anyway, until the SDK bug is fixed.